# how to install autotools on windows machine(autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize pkgconfig)

Tags: windows, android-ndk, linphone

I want to build Linphone android project.I have already downloaded project but unable to follow instructions given in README.Not getting how to install autotools on windows machine.if someone has any idea please help me to install these tools.

Answer (score 2):

Install MingW or Cygwin: http://cygwin.com/install.html

You can choose which packages to install.

Answer (score 2):

well, you should first download all the needed dependencies like ndk version>=8 and Cygwin. you can find the ndk on the android developers site and unpack it at desired location.

Now download the cygwin installer, which is of few KB. when u starts the installer, it will search for the packages and the list of servers. choose a server which is close to your location. from the available package, download the complete Developers branch so that in future u don't get any new problem that u r missing some file or whatever.

after downloading it, install it with the help of Cygwin installer. the installation path should contain any sapce so better to install it at Drive:\Cygwin

now the next step is to setup the environment variable path for the bin directory of both NDK and Cygwin, so do it quickly.. nothing is as simple as this step is :)

now, all the dependencies are available to use. so start the cygwin shell, its similar to the normal CMD.

locate to the root directory of the project by executing the following command :

$ cd

this root directory must contain all the files like manifest files, makefiles and the most importent : prepare_sources.sh

now run the following command :

$ ./prepare_sources.sh /

this complete path to ndk is the path to the ndk-build file in the ndk unpacked source. in my case, its : G:/android-ndk-r8d-windows/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build

Now hit Enter.. n you have completed the main task... now let the Cygwin handle everything including compilation of the native files n all. wait for the cygwin to complate the process... it would need the working high speed internet connection like broadband.

after completion of this process, import the project into eclipse and run it.. :)

I hope it would help you a little bit.. :)

Comment: This is not working after this command "$ ./prepare_sources.sh /" ...
I have installed cygwin, set path variables now what next to compile the code ??

Comment: @Prakash.. what do i have to mention in the "topDir" variable?
its not compiling on my side...i had also set path for both ndk_build_path & ndk_path variables but it is giving error...
Can  you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line

```
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive
```

Then you will get `prepare_sources.sh` inside the **linphone-android directory**

I use the GitShell utility to download from the command line.
Let me know.